# form gets posted when it shouldn't

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

I'm working on an application "guess the number". If the user has used all the guesses, a button shows up (New game) and if the user clicks it the game (of course) starts over.

The problem is that when clicked, the form gets posted and an error message is shown because the input field is empty (validation). I just can't figure out why the form gets posted. The only thing I have inside the code when the New game button gets clicked is a line for resetting the session?

Below is the code from my code-behind file. It's alot of code because I didn't know what I could remove without ruins the possibility of understanding the cause of the problem.

Code behind:

```
private SecretNumber guessNr = null;

private SecretNumber guessSession
{
    get { return Session["guessSession"] as SecretNumber; }
    set { Session["guessSession"] = value; }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void btnCheckNr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (!Page.IsValid) {
        return;
    }

    else {
        if (guessSession == null){
            guessSession = new SecretNumber();
        }

        guessNr = guessSession;

        infoToUser.Visible = true;

        string history = "";
        foreach (var guesses in guessNr.PreviousGuesses) {
            history += "[" + guesses.ToString() + "] ";
        }

        var guessedNr = int.Parse(inputBox.Text);
        var result = (int)guessNr.MakeGuess(guessedNr);

        guessHistory.Text = history;
        lastGuess.Text = "[" + guessedNr.ToString() + "]";

        switch (result){
            case 1:
                messageToUser.Text = " The number is too low.";
                break;
            case 2:
                messageToUser.Text = " The number is too high.";
                break;
            case 3:
                messageToUser.Text = String.Format(" Congratulations! You did it on {0} tries!", guessNr.Count);
                btnCheckNr.Enabled = false;
                inputBox.Enabled = false;
                newGame.Visible = true;
                break;
            case 4:
                messageToUser.Text = String.Format("" Game Over. The number was: {0}"", guessNr.Number);
                btnCheckNr.Enabled = false;
                inputBox.Enabled = false;
                newGame.Visible = true;
                break;
        }
    }
}

protected void btnNewGame_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Session.Abandon();
}
```

Comment: In ASP.NET Web Forms, the entire web application is a form, which means the form (i.e. the ASP.NET Web Forms form that encapsulates every page) is *always* posted. To tell ASP.NET Web Forms that some controls aren't part of the action, you can use things like [ValidationGroup](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/prop_webcontrol_imagebutton_validationgroup.asp). Also, regarding "didn't know what I could remove without ruins the possibility of understanding the cause of the problem"; you should always find, and post, the least amount of code to reproduce the problem. This will make helping easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you have some client side validation kicking off when the button is clicked because it's firing the default validation script.

In which case you should just be able to add this attribute to the new game button:

```
CausesValidation="false"
```